# Only migration option offered is to ask patents meta

Tags: support, migration

A recent question clearly belongs in one of the many stack exchange software sites. When I select close and migrate I get the option to migrate to this meta site - period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration is something we try to limit and one of the ways we do that is to restrict the number of sites any user can suggest a post be migrated to. Sites that are allowed migration paths - graduated sites with custom site designs - may have up to five sites in their close dialogue but these are not configured by default.

In order to have a migration path set up, a site must request it and show that it is needed by having a history of many questions migrated to another site. Ask Patents has never requested this, so they do not have any migration targets other than the default child meta.

That said, your moderators can migrate to any site on the network or its meta site. If you believe a question and its answers are off topic here **and** truly worthy of preserving by moving the question to the appropriate site, feel free to flag that post and point out that it would be on topic elsewhere. Bonus points for you if you're familiar with that site's question quality/scope standards and can assure the moderators that the question would be welcome.

Otherwise, my general recommendation is to vote to close the question and add a comment to let the OP know that their post is off topic but might be welcome on one of our other sites and give them a link to the help/ontopic page for the site you're recommending. In general, the post is better off if asked natively on the other site rather than being migrated.

For more information, see the [Meta Stack Exchange guide to migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). There are some caveats for times a question can not be migrated (over 60 days old, the asker is question banned on the target site, etc) that are covered there if you're interested.

Comment: The reference to "your moderators" does not really apply here, since [the only moderator](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) was not seen since December.

Comment: @user11728 RobertCartaino is more or less actively moderating this site